# SQL What you think is better? All on one place or Separate

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, logic

Which one you think is better? And why?

I always need all data, it will never happen that i need only name and not the "tool1,tool2"...

**1) Lets say i have table "Woods" and "WoodsData"**

Inside "Woods" i have:

- id (auto increment)
- name (name of wood)
- when (when was wood cutted down)

And other table "WoodsData"

- id (wich is linked to woods id)
- tool1 (tool no. 1 used to cutdown the tree, true or false)
- tool2
- tool3
- tool4
- tool5
- times (times used the tool)

so the select would be here by joining two tables!

**2) One table "Woods" wich looks like this:**

- id (auto increment)
- name (name of wood)
- when (when was wood cutted down)
- tool1 (tool no. 1 used to cutdown the tree, true or false)
- tool2
- tool3
- tool4
- tool5
- times (times used the tool)

NOTE: The "tool1,tool2,tool3,tool4,tool5" should go to 50 of them i just didnt wanted to write them all here :P

Comment: Why not have a tools table, with 1-50 (would also be easily expandable), then a lookup table between tools and woods as the woodsdata?

Comment: Because its not mine project, i didnt work on it... some old bastard did who didnt know nothing... And now i have to leave it like that, but i wanted to see what people thing... Is there any difference between those 2 up there? I think not....

Comment: hahaha... revail yourself "downvoter"! Please :P

Comment: FeRtoll, the downvote was probably because it's a poorly worded question, as it currently stands. You wanted to know whether to split this entity across two tables or keep it in one table, but then the data model itself cries out for normalisation.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp The question was sample to sample people! If it bathers you or something just close the window/tab! Thing i needed was solved and no need you to make all smart now. If i could i would delete this question after i discused all but i cant! WDIEWTOY

Comment: Hey, just trying to help you improve the question - and no, it doesn't "bather" me :) ... anyway, the point is, this site exists to help everyone - with some improvement your question could help others, so no need to delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with:

**Woods**

- id (auto increment)
- name (name of wood)
- when (when was wood cutted down)

**Tools**

- id (auto increment)
- name (name of tool)

And then a junction table to show which tools were used on which woods

**Woods_Tools**

- wood_id (Foreign key to Woods.id)
- tool_id (Foreign key to Tools.id)

Comment: that helps me nothing! That wasnt my question... I know i could do it like that and that would be the right thing but my problem are other 1000 problems there so i have to leave it like it is now... The only thing i can change for now is up there in my question! Ahhhh nm. you didnt help! :P

Comment: @FeRtoll Then the correct answer to your question is: It doesn't matter if you do it this way or the other.

Comment: @FeRtoll: If you're unwilling and/or unable to normalize the data properly, then I would just go with your second example (all data in one table).

Comment: @Filburt i think 2 that its same thing

Comment: @JoeStefanelli so i can give him single select to 1 table... no need 2 tables its same thing right?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli lol and i am not unwilling and unable i just dont work on that... a guy asked me this and i just wanted to check what 100000000 people mean... do they think same as me! :D

Comment: @FeRtoll: Yes, as long as the data's denormalized anyhow, you might as well go all the way and put everything into the 1 table.

Comment: k :) Thank's for confirming! ;) I like too know i am not alone :P

Comment: @FeRtoll: So, you were here for a chat, not an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Both are wrong, you should normalize the data: "tool1" to "tool50" should be "tool" in an extra table. Read something about normalisation.

Comment: Ok. But would you be happy with a bad answer?

Comment: Probably more than it looks like i did bad thing :P I should leave it! Its a question like "Is there any difference" and not a suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to put everything in one table. That way you will only have one set of data to insert when an entry is made.

If you have two tables you will need to update two tables (clustered indexes if they are sql server tables with primary keys). That can take extra effort.

As long as you really need all the data (tools1..50) every time you select from the table then I think it is better to use one table.

The best solution is to try it both ways and measure the results. It might not make a difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

To be more normalized, separate the 'tool' entries into a third table

WoodsTool:

- id (primary)
- woodsdata_id (foreign key, relates to WoodsData primary key)

Comment: Not good :( ... I mean it is good :) hehehe but... ahh read my comment under my question!

Comment: @FeRtoll:  Thanks for clarifying.  Next time you should put in the first line of your question "I know this is the wrong way to do it but I'm stuck with it" so you don't get 900 responses to normalize!